# API for getting screen region changes?

Tags: windows, winapi, image-capture

I am writing a sort of screen-recording app for Windows and wish to know when and which regions of the screen/active window have changed.

Is there a Windows API I can hook to get notified of screen changes?

Or would I need to manually write something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76651/)? :(

I always figured that Remote Desktop used some sort of API to detect what regions of the screen had changed and only sent back those images - this is exactly the behavior that I need.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an API in Windows that can tell you which parts of the screen have changed.

One possible way is using a [video mirror driver](http://www.uvnc.com/features/driver.html) like UltraVNC uses.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll find some clues here [Screen Event Recorder DLL/Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/eventrecorder.aspx), here [About Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959(VS.85).aspx), and here [Writing a Macro Recorder/Player using Win32 Journal Hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/winmacro.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that you're going to have to do a fair bit of work to detect screen changes. This posting at [tech-archive.net](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/2005-02/0231.html) for instance. With this you can copy to RAM a reference screen and then take another and compare the two. It'd be up to you to define what kind of a change is a meaningful one. It's similar material to this article on [desktop capture](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30134471/desktop-capture.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think Remote Desktop streams GDI like commands.  I don't know how they capture them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone. I ended up writing an image differencing class which seems to calculate the changed rectangles suprisingly quick. I've posted the gist of how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76651/dirty-rectangles#322354).

At the moment I'm just doing it in a timer but planning to do it after input events too.

Thanks heaps for your links Boost - I've only just looked at this thread again so I'll check them out soon.